# Find directory and replace with symlink

Tags: command-line, bash, symbolic-link

I'm trying to find and replace multiple directories with symlinks, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have 2 root folders, lets say `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html2` and they both contain the same files and folders, for example

```
/var/www/html/project1/lib/config
/var/www/html2/project1/lib/config
/var/www/html/project2/v1/lib/config
/var/www/html2/project2/v1/lib/config
/var/www/html/project2/v2/lib/config
/var/www/html2/project2/v2/lib/config
```

What I want to do is search `/var/www/html` and replace all `config` folders with a symlink to the same folder in `/var/www/html2`, but only if `config` is inside a `lib` folder

I understand that I will have to remove the existing directory (`rm -r /var/www/html/project1/lib/config`) and then create the symlink (`ln -s /var/www/html2/project1/lib/config /var/www/html/project1/lib/config`)

I can do this manually, but I'd like to create a 1 liner or shell script to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Using bash's recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
cd /var/www/html
for d in **/lib/config
do
    echo rm -r "$d"
    echo ln -s /var/www/html2/"$d" "$d"
done
```

Run with `echo` to check, run without it to actually do the linking.

Comment: @Zanna they want to symlink to `/var/www/html2/foo/lib/config` from what I understand, and that's not being deleted here, unless I made a typo

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to do, thank you!